# Как в modx revo вывести мероприятия в два блока 1 которые наступили, и 2 которые ещё не наступили?

Tags: modx, revo

Как вывести на modx revo новости (мероприятия) в зависимости от даты в один или другой блок? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Контент менеджер указывает дату, а исходя из этого мероприятие появляется в том или ином блоке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вопросе не указано, как задается дата. Если она задана в `publishedon`, то можно выбирать новости для каждого из блоков при помощи сниппета `getResourses`, сравнивая дату новости с текущей датой.

Например для первого блока (Новые) вызов сниппета может быть таким (допустим новости являются потомками ресурса с ID == 10):

```
[[getResources?
    &parents=`10`
    &tpl=`news-block-item`
    &includeContent=`1`
    &where=`{"publishedon:>":[[!now]]}`
    &limit=`4`
]]
```

Обратите внимание, `publishedon` хранится в виде UNIX-time и сравнение также должно производиться с аналогичным значением временной отметки. Сниппет `now` может представлять из себя что-то вроде

```
<?php
return date("U");
```

Если дата новости задается в TV (в примере ниже - newsdate), то условие будет другим. Например таким:

```
[[getResources?
    &parents=`10`
    &tpl=`news-block-item`
    &includeContent=`1`
    &tvFilters=`newsdate>>[[!now]]}`
    &limit=`4`
]]
```

Comment: `[[getResources?
    &parents=`8`
    &tpl=`ImmediateEvent`
    &includeContent=`1`
 &includeTVs=`1`
 &processTVs=`1`
    &where=`{"publishedon:>":[[!toDate]]}`
    &limit=`4444`
]]`
Вывожу так, выводится все новости

Comment: Это выводит [[+publishedon]]: 2016-09-01 22:52:11, а это выводит снипет toDate: 2016-09-02 14:40:27, формат сходится, не пойму почему так, может сравнивает длину строк а не числа?

Comment: @ВячеславЯшников Ошибочка вышла. `publishedon` хранится в базе и сравнивается как `timestamp`, а выводится в отформатированном виде. Поэтому этот параметр нужно сравнивать в числовом виде. Я исправил сниппет `now` в ответе.

Comment: @ВячеславЯшников Кроме того нужно понимать, что при хранении даты публикации не учитывается часовой пояс, его нужно учитывать при сравнении

Comment: когда нет ресурсов удовлетворяющих фильтру, выводит вообще все новости, это можно решить как-нибудь?